# how to interupt a program trying to open a file

Tags: ruby

We are making a program write to a file on my computer and there is basically just one part that I can't figure out how it works.

Before the program opens the file the program allows me to press the `Return` key to go ahead to open the file and thus erasing the content. Or I can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to interrupt my program.  I'm thankful for any kind of input here since I really can't seem to find anything about this specific function.

```
filename = ARGV.first
puts "We're going to erase #{filename}"

# This is the part I can't find out how it works.
puts "If you dont want that press ctrl-c (^C)."
puts "If you do want that press RETURN."
$stdin.gets
```

Comment: The [`^C` (Control+C) convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C) as "break" has been around for decades though it is a command-line specific thing. Using that as a way of "aborting" an operation is really non-standard here, the normal approach is to ask "Type yes to confirm" and not do anything unless the input is exactly "yes".

Comment: I see. I will think about that if it isn't introduced into the course as I progress on. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby `gets` reads a line of text. When called on a file - it reads a line of this file. When called on `$stdin` as in your case, it reads a line from the  standard input (a console).

If you press `Enter`, the program will read an empty line and continue execution. If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> a signal is sent to the program and this signal make program to stop execution. You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in any moment of program execution and it will be stopped (unless the signal is handled in the program, but it's not the case here).

See also:

- [gets docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#gets-method)
- [question about Ctrl-C](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510811/what-is-the-difference-between-ctrl-z-and-ctrl-c-in-the-terminal)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. One last question. Is the (^C) part of the code really neccesery?

Comment: If you referring to the line which starts with `puts`, no. It is only part of the string which will be printed on the screen.

Comment: @BillyLarssonLundgren if the answer is helpful, pls consider accepting it (green tick besides the arrows)

Comment: Thanks guys! I think I accepted it correctly this time.